# Regexp for numbers with delimeters

Tags: php

I would like to know how can I create a regexp to match the pattern  3,231 or 3,231,201 in php ?
Thanks

Comment: @Esailija, ([0-9]*k?), thats regexp is for the numbers 118k for example or for 118, but I would like it to cover the possibility of 118,201 and 118,201,100 for example

Comment: Do you want to match or reject incorrectly grouped numbers like 1234,5678 or 1,2,345? Also, how about other delimiters (remember, in Europe, the comma is used as the decimal separator) or other grouping conventions like for example [in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Asian_numbering_system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/([0-9,]+k?)/
```

The above regex will match numbers, comma, with an optional 'k' in the end.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern could look like this:

```
/([0-9]+)(,[0-9]{3})*/
```

This will allow for something like:

```
123
123,123
123,123,123
1,123
123456
```

but not:

```
123,
123,1
123,12
123,1234
```

You can modify the behaviour, e.g. allowing for more/less digits after the comma by changing `{3}` into `+` or `{1,4}` (1 to 4) or `{3,}` (3 or more).

Comment: Also, if you just want to localize numbers, you might want to look into: `number_format()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

Well that is pretty easy;

```
/^[0-9,]+$/
```

this works with (for example) `1231,1231,1312,12312`